# Unity - перемещение объекта с помощью зажатой правой кнопки мышки в 3D пространстве

Tags: unity3d

давненько я хотел попробовать создать градостроительный симулятор и сразу столкнулся с проблемой, а именно перемещение здания за курсором и при этом, чтобы здание двигалось не плавно, а по так называемым "клеткам". Всё это я вижу так
1)Допустим размер клетки 1x1 и все здания изначально спавнятся в центре экрана
2)Затем мы нажимаем на здание и удерживаем ПКМ
3)Потом бы постоянно берём координату курсора, округляем до целого числа и  присваиваем объекту(тобиж здание).
4)Когда отжимаем ПКМ, координаты выбранного места сохраняются

Знаний у меня, пока не много и вот всё, что я смог сделать за весь день:

```
public bool MouseDOWN = false;
public GameObject House;

Vector3 Cursor;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    MouseDOWN = true;
}

private void OnMouseUp()
{
    MouseDOWN = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    Cursor = Input.mousePosition;
    Cursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Cursor);

    if (MouseDOWN == true)        
    {
        House.transform.position = Cursor;
    }  
}
```

}

P.s. Возможно это Super easy, но моих 15 летних мозгов на это не хватает.

Comment: Ваш пост больше похож на ТЗ, а не вопрос. Описано, что хочется получить в итоге, но не проблемы. Если не хватает мозгов, как вы написали, не беритесь, тут их не отсыпают. Это не Super easy, это основы на которые болт не положишь. Если вы не способны написать конструктор `Vector3`, тут не о чем разговаривать. Учите основы.

Comment: @Yaroslav полностью согласен свами, но как то жёстко вы сним.

Answer (score 0):

Ну... В вашем коде многое не хватает и вообще не понятно что это и зачем вы его писали.

```cs
    Cursor = Input.mousePosition;
    Cursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Cursor);
```

Проблема даже не в том, что вы не умейте работать с координатами, а в том что, то что вы описали сверху, не написать даже в течении недели.
Как решить эту задачу?

- Сперва вам понадобится высшая математика. Убедитесь что вы хорошо знайте её.
- Во вторых пытайтесь написать что-то сам. В случае проблем обращайтесь в Stack Overflow.
- Задавайте короткие и конкретные вопросы, а не целый проект.
- Прежде чем задать вопрос ищите решение в интернете.

А вопрос этот я бы посоветовал удалить. Он не содержит полезной информации и принесёт вам только минусы.